# Reassign values with conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the following code we assign value 0.5 to variable b. Then we assign a letter to variables L1 and L2, and store it in a dictionary.
In the end, we have 4 equations (P11, P12, P21, P22) in which we add up those variables.

**My concrete question:**

How can I "reassign" (in each equation) value 0 to b, only if both dictionary values are 0?

My question in pseudocode:

```
In all the equations Pii:
if Di[Li]==0 and Di[Li]==0:
then b==0
```

My code:

```
import random
b=0.5
L1= random.choice("ABCDEFGH")
L2= random.choice("ABCDEFGH")
D1 = {"A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0,"E":0,"F":0,"G":0,"H":0}
D2 = {"A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0,"E":0,"F":0,"G":0,"H":0}
for n in range(1):
    D1[L1] += 1
for n in range(1):
    D2[L2] += 1

P11=D1[L1]+D2[L1]+b
P12=D1[L2]+D2[L2]+b
P21=D1[L1]+D2[L2]+b
P22=D1[L2]+D2[L1]+b

print P11, P12, P21, P22
```

In this case I expect to obtain:

```
P11= 1 + 0 + 0.5
P12= 0 + 1 + 0.5
P21= 1 + 1 + 0.5
P22= 0 + 0 + 0
```

Comment: Please also mention the result you get and what you expect. Your code seems to do as per what you mentioned it should be doing (as per the current content)

Comment: I've added the expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't change the value of `b`, just change whether or not you add `b`:

```
def with_b(x, y):
    result = x + y
    if not (x == y == 0):
        result += b
    return result

P11 = with_b(D1[L1], D2[L1])
P12 = with_b(D1[L2], D2[L2])
P21 = with_b(D1[L1], D2[L2])
P22 = with_b(D1[L2], D2[L1])
```

Comment: Yes, I wanna have value 0 in b only when values stored in the dictionary are both 0. Thanks.

Comment: @pyring how's that?

Comment: I've added the result I expect to obtain but is not the same that I obtain with your code. Thanks for you help anyway

Comment: @pyring woops, made a mistake. Fixed it.

Comment: Excellent! I was trying to do something similar. I'm learning Python and people like you are very helpful. Since I do not have enough rank in the English version of stackoverflow, I still can not vote your answer as it deserves (only ticks). But I will do so as soon as I qualify. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what is your final goal but if I understood well, your question is : "how to use conditions ?"
You can do something based on this synthax :

```
if(dictionnaryValue1==0 and dictionnaryValue2==0):
   b=0
```

And I don't understand your loop "for" : `for n in range(1)`
The code in the loop is executed only one time...